# Dockerfile COPY ".env" directory

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

How can I use `COPY` in `Dockerfile` to copy folder of which name starts with a dot?

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.0.0

# does not work
COPY ./aws/ /home/appuser/.aws

EXPOSE 8083
```

Directory structure:

```
/MyFolder
├── .aws
│   └── credentials
└── Dockerfile
```

Comment: `COPY ./aws` is "copy from current directory the directory named 'aws'". `COPY ./.aws` should work.

Comment: Wouldn't suggest `COPY`'ing credentials into an image, definitely shouldn't share that. Would suggest mounting the credentials during the runtime i.e.: `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/.aws/credentials:/home/appuser/.aws/credentials:ro myimage`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Right now I am trying a POC, that's why I need to copy the `.aws`. `COPY ./.aws` copies the contents of the `.aws` directory only. I need the destination folder `.aws` as well.

Comment: do you expect .aws directory to be present at target or you want to create and copy

Comment: `COPY ./.aws/ /home/appuser/.aws` will result in having `/home/appuser/.aws/credentials` available inside the running container.

Comment: @sanjay I want to copy the `.aws` and add it to the destination: `/home/appuser/.aws`. The `/home/appuser/.aws` directory does not exist prior to COPY

Comment: @Catalin the destination directory will be created by the `COPY`, isn't a problem. Check my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COPY ./aws [DESTINATION]` is "`COPY`, from the current directory '`./`', the directory named '`aws`' to the `[DESTINATION]`".

`COPY ./.aws [DESTINATION]` will `COPY` the hidden directory '`.aws`' from the current directory '`./`' to `[DESTINATION]`.

`COPY ./.aws/ /home/appuser/.aws` will result in `/home/appuser/.aws/credentials` existing in the built image.

---

***Tip***: `[DESTINATION]` is created by `COPY` if it doesn't already exist.

**Note**: if the directory is ignored in a `.dockerignore` then the `COPY` will not work.

**Note**: should never `COPY` credentials in an image if you intend on sharing the image rather bind-mount the credentials during the containers runtime i.e. `docker run --rm -it -v ./.aws/credentials:/home/appuser/.aws/credentials:ro myimage`

Comment: `COPY ./.aws/ /home/appuser/.aws` works. For any other noobies like me, use `bash ls -a` to show hidden directories as well. `.aws` was treated as a hidden directory and `bash ls` would not display it

Answer (score 0):

change your .env file to thisisthenameofthefile.env and Dockerfile should recognize it.